# Stretching and resize a div dynamically

Tags: css, html, resize, stretching

I am trying to stretch div as soon as some text is loaded.I am able to do that by giving min-height:140 px and height:100% to its parent container. But content in my div is crossing its parent container. How can I limit the inner div so that it will not cross its parent container.

Please help me as I am trying for it from so long.

thanks in advance

HP

Comment: some code will be a good way to show what you are trying to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `overflow` attribute in your CSS.

```
#myDiv {
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Depending on the width you assign, this will get the nested div to display a scrollbar once it's width exceeds that of its parent.

Comment: To be fair +1 we had given the same answer but its always the matter of minutes on S.O. sorry you deserve that.Thats the only thing I could do for you.

Answer (score 1):

Every single element on a page is a rectangular box. The sizing, positioning, and behavior of these boxes can all be controlled via CSS. By behavior, I mean how the box handles it when the content inside and around it changes. For example, if you don't set the height of a box, the height of that box will grow as large as it needs to be to accommodate the content. But what happens when you do set a specific height or width on a box, and the content inside cannot fit? That is where the CSS overflow property comes in, allowing you to specify how you would like that handled.

```
overflow:auto;
```

**Reference**

**[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)**
[**css tricks**](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/)

Comment: hmmm, you are talking to @Mohammad here while this is not his answer :)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks for your comment...+1